# How to avoid "Assignment to property of function parameter 'elem'" eslint rule?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I want to understand how you guys avoid the [eslint warning "Assignment to property of function parameter 'elem'"](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign). I know that is a good pattern do not change function parameters values. This keeps our code decoupled and with high maintenance. However, in some cases, I come across with the following situation.
I need to retrieve all elements with a specific class, and then, change its display style property.
This is my code:

```
const setDisplayStyleToElementsArray = (arr, display) => {
  arr.map((elem) => {
    elem.style.display = display;
    return elem;
  });
};

const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('.myClass');

const myFields = [].slice.call(elements, 0);

setDisplayStyleToElementsArray(myFields, 'block');
```

In this case, I'm changing the property "block" of all my .myClass elements. How to do this without side effects? What is the correct way of doing that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Cleaner way: `let myFields = [... elements] `

Comment: Just an observation: use `forEach` instead of `map` (as you are not using the returned array).

Comment: Curious to know why you're using `.map()` but ignoring the new array it's creating. Was this an attempt at a solution to the ESLint warning?

Comment: I just tried your code with that ESLint setting, and I don't get the error, which makes sense since you're not assigning to the parameter itself. `tinyurl.com/y8c7tv79`

Comment: is this a syntactic sugar for the method call when delegating for arrays? (square brackets with spread operator)? @epascarello

Comment: Thanks @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: This was a mistake @rockstar, I will replace with a forEach method. Thanks.

Comment: Eslint set the property `/*eslint no-param-reassign: ["error", { "props": false }]*/` by default. But not airbnb style guide. @rockstar

Comment: It is how the spread operator works on iterating over the collection. Other option is `Array.from(elements)` which is also IMO cleaner than the ES5 way.

Comment: Ah I see. It needed `{"props":true}`. Thanks @PabloDarde

Answer (score 0):

> I'm changing the property. How to do this without side effects?

You cannot. Changing that DOM property *is* a side effect. If your linter prevents you from doing that, disable it (on that line at least).

Of course, this specific rule can be avoided by simply not using `map` or a callback function. Much more idiomatic would be

```
function setDisplayStyles(arr, display) {
  for (const elem of arr) {
    elem.style.display = display;
  }
}

const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('.myClass'));
setDisplayStyles(elements, 'block');
```

Comment: I wonder why that would help avoid the rule. The `arr` parameter is still being mutated.

Comment: @rockstar I don't think ESLint is clever enough to figure out the relation between `elem` and `arr`. In the original code, `elem` was a function parameter itself.

Comment: for a forEach() which would be a minimal change from the OPs original code

Comment: Could be. I couldn't get ESLint to show a warning for this at all, and I assumed it was because `elem` itself was not mutated, but rather its `.style` property's object.

Comment: @epascarello `forEach` must die! (It causes too much trouble when you try to `break`, `return` or `await` in it) I like to use proper control structures for side-effectful code, and try to avoid the ugly `forEach` in general.

Comment: Than if you need to do any of those, than forEach is a bad choice. It is like opening a window with a hammer. It works, but it may not always be the best solution. You pick the right tool for the right job. A lot of times when I see people need to exit from forEach they should have been using every or some.

Comment: Now I got the error with the OP's comment above, and `for-of` does indeed fix it, so you're right that they just don't follow the references all the way through. I also confirmed this by taking the original, and assigning `var el = elem;` and then operating on `el`, which also avoided the error.

Comment: Well, regarding the `forEach` or `map`, I think we can use the `some` method, which returns `true` if the condition is true.

Comment: @PabloDarde No, you want a loop here, and not return a boolean, so you should use a `for of` loop and not the `some` method.

Comment: @Bergi, I liked very much your solution, however, my atom eslint extension,  showed me the following: **iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight. loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations.**

Comment: @PabloDarde Just configure your transpiler to emit array iteration code ([here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-for-of/#optionsloose) or [there](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-for-of-as-array)), not generic iterator code then. Don't we use transpilers for the sole purpose of having nice syntax to read?

Comment: Not only for this @Bergi, but also to avoid antipatterns, I believe.

Comment: @PabloDarde Recognising and warning about antipatterns is the job of linters, not transpilers.

Comment: @bergi, codeclimate showed me a warning. Please, what do you think about that? https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/851

Comment: I think you should understand what things the warning tries to prevent, and then ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

At first, thanks for all comments, appreciate. After some research about this issue with my coworkers, and on the web, I came across with a [Lecture by Douglas Crockford](http://bdadam.com/blog/video-douglas-crockford-about-the-new-good-parts.html) talking about that among other things. Although the answer above seems to be simple and elegant, it doesn't seem to be the most performative IMHO. So, if someone has a better opinion about that, please, let me know.

Basically, I decided to use `Object.keys(htmlCollection).forEach(...)` instead of `for`, agreeing with Douglas Crockford thoughts. This way, codeclimate didn't throw any warning and my code seemed to be more logic and fluid.

```js
const setDisplayStyleToElementsArray = (arr, display) => {
 Object.keys(arr).forEach(field => arr[field].classList.add('hidden'));
};

const elements = [... document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')];
setDisplayStyleToElementsArray(elements, 'none');
```

```css
.myClass {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hidden {
  border: 1px solid blue; //could be display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">One</div>
<div class="myClass">Two</div>
```